# Recognizing a fiber product of schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic not 2 or 3. Consider the map $\text{spec}(k[t])\rightarrow \text{spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ given by the ring map $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$. (This is just the normalizalition of the nodal cubic). Then consider the map from $\text{spec}(k[\![t]\!])\rightarrow \text{spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ defined similarly by the ring map $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$. What is the fiber product $\text{spec}(k[\![t]\!]) \times_{\text{spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)} \text{spec}(k[t])$?

I believe it should be $\text{spec}(k[\![t]\!][s]/(st,s^2)) $, because the if we consider the inclusion of the origin into $\text{spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ then the pullback along the normalization is $\text{spec}(k[s]/(s^2))$, but I am unsure how to compute this using the tensor product. I believe one can do it by carefully using the universal property of tensor products to construct a map $k[\![t]\!][s]/(st,s^2)) \rightarrow k[\![t]\!] \otimes_{(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)}k[t]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your quotient ideal may be a little too big. The correct ring may be calculated as follows (note that $k[s]\otimes_{k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)}k[t]$ is finite over $k[s]$):
\begin{align*}
k[[s]]\otimes_{k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)}k[t] &\cong k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s]}k[s,t]/(s^2-t^2,s^3-t^3) \\
&\cong k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s]}k[s,t]/(s^2-t^2,(s+t)(s^2-t^2)-st(s-t)) \\
&\cong k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s]}k[s,t]/((s+t)(s-t),st(s-t)) \\
&\cong k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s],s=(u+v)/2}k[u,v]/(uv,u(u^2-v^2)/4) \\
&\cong k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s],s=u+v}k[u,v]/(uv,u^3),
\end{align*}
where $u:=s-t,v:=s+t$.
It is clear that for any $N\geq 3$, the following equality of ideals holds in $k[u,v]/(uv,u^3)$:
$$((u+v)^N) = (v^N) = (u,v)^N.$$
This implies that
$$
k[[s]]\otimes_{k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)}k[t]\cong k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s],s=u+v}k[u,v]/(uv,u^3) \cong k[[u,v]]/(uv,u^3).
$$

Comment: Good answer! PS, minor grammatical correction: "calculated the followings" should be "calculated as follows". The 'as follows' is a set phrase (成語). I hope you don't mind me pointing this out.

Comment: PPS, I agree with your calcuations, but what is the intuition here for the degree 3? Is it because the normalization is like 'pinching a point together with itself', and so similarly for the map from the power series ring, so the fiber product is now like...3 points pinched togehter?

Comment: @AlexYoucis The intuition here why I asked, and I understand it as follows. There is a valuative criteria for flat maps in Ravi Vakil's lecture notes, it basically says that given a flat map $X\rightarrow Y$ and a map from spec of a DVR into $Y$, associated points of the pullback must not to the closed point of the DVR. Because normalizations aren't flat the nilpotency is reflecting the the way the tangent space suddenly increases dimension at 0. In the pullback nilpotent part in the u direction doesn't extend to the v direction, displaying the jump. I am confused why it's 3 and not 2 though.

Comment: @AlexYoucis The tangent space of $\text{spec}(k[u]/(u^3))$ is two dimensional, like the tangent space at the origin of the nodal cubic. Now that I am thinking about it maybe one should see the pullback as recording the fact that the tangent space doesn't vary well along the singular point, neither of the "two tangent vectors" can be moved from the origin. I figured it record the fact the tangent space jumps in dimension by 1, but I suppose the point is that neither "tangent vector in the u direction" can be moved away from the origin.

Comment: It's worth saying explicitly that the answer above is the same as $k[\![v]\!][u]/(uv,u^3)$, a point with power series in one direction and degree 3 nilpotency in another.

Comment: @AlexYoucis [>PS]. Thank you for your grammatical correction, Alex. Actually, I join this community to improve my English skill, so a comment such as yours is very helpful for me.

Comment: I don't understand the $\otimes_{k[s]}$. I get that the ring is $k[[t]]\otimes_{k[t^2,t^3]} k[t^2,t^3,x]/(x^2-t^2,x^3-t^3) = k[[t]][x]/(x^2-t^2,x^3-t^3) $

Comment: @reuns : For avoiding confusion, I use distinct notations of the both hand side of the tensor. As the ring $k[s]\otimes_{k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)}k[t]$ is finite over $k[s]$, the completion can be descrived as $k[[s]]\otimes_{k[s]}(-)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis [>PPS] : I thought the reason of this behavior of the tensor, but this is a little difficult. By drowing the 4 lines $s=0, t=0, u=s-t=0, v = s+t=0$ in the $(s,t)$ plane (and tilting by $\pi/4$ i.e., retaking the coordinate with $(u,v)$), the $v=0$ component of the two vectors determined by $s=0$ and $t=0$ are "overlaping". I think this suggest that "high order nilpotency" of the function $u$.

Comment: @YJ_cat Thank you for your explanation. That definitely helps, but I still don't see where the multiplicity of $3$ for $u^e$ comes from intuitively. As for the English correction: no problem, I have many kind people to correct my Japanese so it's the least I can do. (PS, it should be 'English skills', because there are several aspects to English that one must master, and therefore its 'skills' (plural) and not 'skill' (singular)).

Comment: @Dcoles Yeah, that flatness point is a good one, and also why I knew that there must be a nilpotentcy, and I guess the two-dimensionality of the tangent space still feels related to the fact that the normalization of the cuspidal cubic can be seen as 'pinching $\infty$ together with itself' (in a way that can be made precise), and this map from $\mathrm{Spec}(k[\![t]\!])$ does the same thing, so the fiber product feels like it's pinching $3$ copies of $\infty$ together, which should have something like a 3-dimensional tangent space. Not sure though. YJ_cat's explanation is also clarifying.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think, to solve this problem, we have to compute the scheme-theoretic intersection of the varieties determined by $s^2=t^2$ and $s^{2N+1}=t^{2N+1}$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, this problem is equivalent to the problem computing the intersection of $st=0$ and $s\times \prod_{i=1}^{2N} (s-a_it)=0$, where $a_i \neq 0," \infty"$ are distinct elements of $k$. Then the component $\prod_{i=1}^{2N} (s-a_it)$ is projected in $t$-direction and appears infinitesimally by order $2N$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain why this multiplicity is 3, without changing the original problem to another equivalent problem.